# Notation matter concerning 'or'-elimination

Tags: logic, proof-verification, notation, natural-deduction

I have to show that $\{(\phi\lor\psi),(\lnot\phi)\}\vdash\psi$ using the following natural deduction rule:

[image]

I don't know which of these is correct in term of notation:

[image]

[image]

Could you please tell me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wish to prove $\dfrac{(\phi\vee\psi)\quad (\neg \phi)}{\psi}$ using $\require{cancel}\dfrac{(\phi^1\vee \psi^2)\quad \dfrac{(\cancelto{1}[color=gray]{\color{black}\phi}\wedge\neg\phi)}{\psi}{\small ?}\quad \dfrac{(\cancelto{2}[color=gray]{\color{black}\psi}\wedge\neg\phi)}{\psi}{\small ?}}{\psi}{\small\vee\mathsf E}$

Clearly the second justification is conjunction elimination, where as the first involves a negation elimination.

$$\require{cancel}\dfrac{(\phi^1\vee \psi^2)\quad \dfrac{\dfrac{(\cancelto{1}[color=gray]{\color{black}\phi}\wedge\neg\phi)}{\bot}{\small\neg\mathsf E}}{\psi}{\small\sf RAA}\quad \dfrac{(\cancelto{2}[color=gray]{\color{black}\psi}\wedge\neg\phi)}{\psi}{\small\wedge\mathsf E}}{\psi}{\small\vee\mathsf E}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So simply writing $\dfrac{\cancelto{2}[color=gray]{\color{black}\psi}}{\psi}$ instead of $\dfrac{(\cancelto{2}[color=gray]{\color{black}\psi}\land\neg\phi)}{\psi}\small{(\land E)}$ when appliying $(\lor E)$ is wrong?

Comment: @Scientifica Yes. It's basically a proof by cases. You assume either $\phi$ or $\psi$ (from the disjunction) along with the premise $\neg \phi$ and show that either case entails $\psi$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I didn't missunderstand you, I think you didn't understand well my question. I understand the $(\lor E)$ rule and have no problem with how it is applied. My real question is purely notational: you wrote, in the case where $\psi$ is correct, that it entails $\psi$ as follows: $\dfrac{(\cancelto{2}[color=gray]{\color{black}\psi}\wedge\neg\phi)}{\psi}$. To be even more precise you can use $(\land I)$ to show how $(\psi\land\lnot\phi)$ comes from $\{\psi,\lnot\phi\}$...

Comment: ... In my case I use the fact that if $\psi$ is the true statement (from the disjunction) then it entails itself. Simply writing $\psi$ means that it is true, but it's written as a conclusion, not an assumption. When we cancel $\psi$ to apply $(\lor E)$, it is normally cancelled as an assumption in the derivation of the conclusion we're seeking to (namely $\psi$) so normally we can do it the way you did or in what seems easier (because you have a $(\land I)$ followed by a $(\land E)$) writing it as I did (with my hand I apologize) in the first picture. My thought is: the 2ndpicture is correct?

Comment: @Scientifica Well, I would agree that "Both Case 1 *and the other premise(s)*, and Case 2 *alone*, entail the required conclusion so..." is a valid argument.  But you do at least need to include $\neg \phi$ premise in the case 1 branch.

Comment: Wait!  Is the top line that image supposed to be $\underline{\phi\quad(\neg \phi)}$ ?  I was reading it as $\underline{\phi\vdash \phi\vert}$ .  No wonder it wasn't making sense.

Comment: Indeed it's supposed to be $\phi\quad (\lnot\phi)$. I apologize for writing with my hand (more precisely using a mouse instead of a tablet which I don't own) instead of using LaTeX. It's my fault, sorry. Thank you very much for the previous comment. It answers my question. Sorry for perturbing you by my writing.